# Как отзеркалить изображение через Opencv на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Нужно сделать функцию отзеркаливания изображения по вертикали/горизонтали.

```py
def mirror(image,orient):
    if orient=="horizontal":
        # put your code here
    if orient=="vertical"
        # put your code here
```

В сети не нашел информации как это сделать с помощью Opencv на Python.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Берите срез `img[::-1]` для переворачивания по вертикали и `img[:,::-1]` для горизонтали

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите отзеркалить изображение более явным способом, можно воспользоваться методом [cv2.flip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-flip-method/).

Используйте так:

```
res = cv2.flip(src, flipCode)
```

Если flipCode = 0, разворот будет вокруг горизонтальной оси. Если > 0 — вокруг вертикальной. При отрицательных значениях разворот будет происходить по обеим осям одновременно.